# Div are not properly aligning in JSP page

Tags: html, css, jsp

I need a page to be aligned in the following way,

[image: Aligned Page]

My Left Navigation contains all the links. On the right div there is a top div which will have a constant height. Contents page will display the contents when clicked on a left navigation link. This content page should occupy the remaining height.

Following code is what I have tried.

css:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    widht: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.leftMenu {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
    position: absolute;
}

.rightMenu {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}

.row1 {
    height: 10%;
    background: red;
}

.row2 {
    height: 90%;
    background: green;
}
```

JSP page:

```
<body>

    <div id="mainDiv">
        <div id="leftDiv" class="leftMenu">
            <ul>
                <li id="page1"> Page - 1 </li>
                <li id="page2"> Page - 2 </li>
                <li id="page3"> Page - 3 </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="contentDiv" class="rightMenu">

            <div id="topDiv" class="row1">
                <label>Servlet and Jsp Examples</label> <br>
            </div>

            <div id="ContentDiv" class="row2">
                <label>Content 1</label> <br>
                <label>Content 2</label> <br>
                <label>Content 3</label> <br>
                <label>Content 4</label> <br>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Problem is that my right div coming below the left div and the contents div is not occupying the remaining space at bottom.

Please look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Amarnath510/tsyL7/2/) also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

**CSS:**

```
#mainDiv { height: 100%; }

.leftMenu {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
    position: fixed;  /* <-- fix the left panel to prevent from scrolling */
}

.rightMenu {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 20%; /* <-- pull out the right panel from under the left one */
}

.row1 {
    min-height: 10%; /* <-- fix the height issue when content grows */
    background: red;
}

.row2 {
    min-height: 90%; /* <-- fix the background-color issue when content grows */
    background: green;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/tsyL7/6/)**

Comment: Exactly .. +1 .. But can you just pls let me know what mistake I have done?

Comment: @Che I added related comments inside to explain :)